# How to open serial-port with root privileges

Tags: linux, sudo, permissions, root

When I try to open `/dev/ttyUSB0` with `serial-term`, following permission error shows:

```
Opening serial port: Permission denied, /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I know I can add my user to a group that has access to `/dev/tty*`. Probably something like:

```
# sudo usermod -aG tty $(whoami)
```

However, Is there anyway to access `/dev/ttyUSB0` within emacs (just put my password, whenever I access to serial ports, without changing my user groups). Perhaps something like run `M-x serial-term` with root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use TRAMP. There are likely dozens of other questions you can consult which document it, plus there is [a manual you can read](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). You can also read it inside of Emacs by typing `C-h i`.

Comment: Could you explain little more? or tell me around which section of TRAMP should I read?